# How to tell who is accessing my server by IP instead of FQDN (SFTP)

Tags: windows-server-2008, sftp

Long story short, we have 100 or so clients.  Some access us by IP (1.1.1.1), and some access us by IP ftp.contoso.com.  We use Bitwise SFTP server if that is helpful.  Is there any way we can detect who is accessing us by IP?  Bitwise does have logs but I don't think it has the useful info.

Note this was done before I got here, I implemented the ftp.contoso.com on new clients.

This is needed b/c in 3 weeks we are moving our server, and probably will not be able to retain that IP address.

Answer (score 0):

SFTP (SSH FTP), like SSH itself (and unlike HTTP) doesn't have any information that could help you with this. If necessary, the client will resolve the IP address for the hostname or use the IP directly and connect to that IP. The protocol doesn't have any way to tell the server which hostname the client tried to connect to.

Comment: Under some circumstances, it might be possible to scan the log files of your DNS server to see who is trying to resolve `ftp.contoso.com`,  with the assumption that clients that don't do this use the IP address. However, this is messy and unreliable.